# Java static inner classes returning null

Tags: java, android, static, inner-classes

I am having an issue trying to create an instance of the kanji class. It should have 2 static inner classes. Each of the inner classes should hold two strings.

when i instantiate the class it returns the two static inner classes as nulls.

Full class is below. Is my constructor correct? If i dont have the inner classes and their strings as static i get an error thrown.

```
Kanji kanji = new Kanji("aaa","bbb","ccc","ddd","eee","fff" );
```

My class

```
public class Kanji {

public String character;
public String meaning;
public Onyomi onyomi;
public Kunyomi kunyomi;

public static class Onyomi {
    public static String romaji;
    public static String katakana;
    public String getRomaji() {
        return romaji;
    }

    public void setRomaji(String romaji) {
        this.romaji = romaji;
    }

    public String getKatakana() {
        return katakana;
    }

    public void setKatakana(String katakana) {
        this.katakana = katakana;
    }

}
public static class Kunyomi {
    public static String romaji;
    public static String hiragana;

    public String getRomaji() {
        return romaji;
    }

    public void setRomaji(String romaji) {
        this.romaji = romaji;
    }

    public String getHiragana() {
        return hiragana;
    }

    public void setHiragana(String hiragana) {
        this.hiragana = hiragana;
    }
}

public Kanji(String character_, String meaning_, String oR_, String oK_, String kR_, String kH_) {
    this.character = character_;
    this.meaning = meaning_;
    this.onyomi.romaji = oR_;
    this.onyomi.katakana = oK_;
    this.kunyomi.romaji = kR_;
    this.kunyomi.hiragana = kH_;
}

public String getCharacter() {
    return character;
}

public void setCharacter(String character) {
    this.character = character;
}

public String getMeaning() {
    return meaning;
}

public void setMeaning(String meaning) {
    this.meaning = meaning;
}

public Onyomi getOnyomi() {
    return onyomi;
}

public void setOnyomi(Onyomi onyomi) {
    this.onyomi = onyomi;
}

public Kunyomi getKunyomi() {
    return kunyomi;
}

public void setKunyomi(Kunyomi kunyomi) {
    this.kunyomi = kunyomi;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is 2 problems in this code.

The first one ( causing the fact that the `onyomi` and `kunyomi` fields are null ) is that, in your constructor code, you don't initialize these variables, so no, the constructor is incorrect

What you need to add in the constructor is these 2 lines :

```java
this.onyomi = new Onyomi();
this.kunyomi = new Kunyomi();
```

before setting `onyomi` and `kunyomi` fields, like this :

```java
public Kanji(String character_, String meaning_, String oR_, String oK_, String kR_, String kH_) {
    this.character = character_;
    this.meaning = meaning_;
    this.onyomi = new Onyomi();
    this.kunyomi = new Kunyomi();
    this.onyomi.romaji = oR_;
    this.onyomi.katakana = oK_;
    this.kunyomi.romaji = kR_;
    this.kunyomi.hiragana = kH_;
}
```

The second problem appears with this test code :

```java
Kanji ima = new Kanji("今","now","ima_on","イマ","ima_kun","いま" );
    System.out.println(ima);
    Kanji kuruma = new Kanji("車", "car", "kuruma_on", "クルマ", "kuruma_kun", "くるま");
    System.out.println(kuruma);
    System.out.println(ima);
```

I added a toString function is the Kanji class like this :

```java
public String toString() {
    return "Character="+character+" - Meaning="+meaning + "\nKunyomi=" + this.kunyomi.getRomaji() + "/" + this.kunyomi.getHiragana() + " - Onyomi="+onyomi.getRomaji()+"/"+onyomi.getKatakana();
}
```

And it produced this output :

```
Character=今 - Meaning=now
Kunyomi=ima_kun/いま - Onyomi=ima_on/イマ
Character=車 - Meaning=car
Kunyomi=kuruma_kun/くるま - Onyomi=kuruma_on/クルマ
Character=今 - Meaning=now
Kunyomi=kuruma_kun/くるま - Onyomi=kuruma_on/クルマ
```

As you can see, creating the Kanji object holding the 'car' kanji information also changed the toString result of the Kanji object holding 'now' kanji information

The problem here is that the fields in Onyomi and Kunyomi classes are static, meaning that there will be only one copy of these fields in the whole application ( or one copy per Onyomi/Kunyomi classes loaded, i'm not sure about that ), instead of one copy per Onyomi/Kunyomi object created.

That means that everytime you create a new Kanji object, the Kanji constructor will erase the previous Kunyomi romaji and hiragana field, and the previous Onyomi romaji and katakana field.

So you might want to remove the static modifier of the fields, like this :

```java
public static class Onyomi {
    public String romaji;
    public String katakana;
    public String getRomaji() {
        return romaji;
    }

    public void setRomaji(String romaji) {
        this.romaji = romaji;
    }
    public String getKatakana() {
        return katakana;
    }
    public void setKatakana(String katakana) {
        this.katakana = katakana;
    }

}
public static class Kunyomi {
    public String romaji;
    public String hiragana;

    public String getRomaji() {
        return romaji;
    }

    public void setRomaji(String romaji) {
        this.romaji = romaji;
    }

    public String getHiragana() {
        return hiragana;
    }

    public void setHiragana(String hiragana) {
        this.hiragana = hiragana;
    }
}
```

With that, the previous test code output this :

```
Character=今 - Meaning=now
Kunyomi=ima_kun/いま - Onyomi=ima_on/イマ
Character=車 - Meaning=car
Kunyomi=kuruma_kun/くるま - Onyomi=kuruma_on/クルマ
Character=今 - Meaning=now
Kunyomi=ima_kun/いま - Onyomi=ima_on/イマ
```

Also, the Kanji initialize itself the fields of the Kunyomi / Onyomi created objects. It should be the Kunyomi / Onyomi constructor jobs to do that :

In the Onyomi class code, add these constructors :

```java
    public Onyomi() {
        romaji = null;
        katakana = null;
    }

    public Onyomi(String romaji, String katakana) {
        this.romaji = romaji;
        this.katakana = katakana;
    }
```

In the Kunyomi class, add these constructors :

```java
    public Kunyomi() {
        romaji = null;
        hiragana = null;
    }

    public Kunyomi(String romaji, String hiragana) {
        this.romaji = romaji;
        this.hiragana = hiragana;
    }
```

And in the Kanji constructor, you will be able to do the way you did, or this way :

```java
public Kanji(String character_, String meaning_, String oR_, String oK_, String kR_, String kH_) {
    this.character = character_;
    this.meaning = meaning_;
    this.onyomi = new Onyomi(oR_, oK_);
    this.kunyomi = new Kunyomi(kR_, kH_);
}
```

Comment: Great explantion. ありがとう

Comment: どういたしまして、user2202098さん

Answer (score 1):

Your constructor is not assigning any instance to variables: onyomi, kunyomi. The classes may be static but the variables are not. Either way at some point they need initialization.

```
this.onyomi.romaji = oR_;
this.onyomi.katakana = oK_;
```

Before these two lines there is no initialization of the variables. In fact the constructor is throwing an NPE on those two lines. Unless you are using the default constructor.